# Создание коллекции ListView и ее вывод

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Приложение на подобие "Проводника": слева TreeView, а по нажатию на каталог слева в ListView должны вывестись имя файла, расширение и размер. Наткнулся на какой-то пример в инете, пытался сделать под своё, но данные упорно не хотят выводиться. Помогите, пожалуйста.

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace lab1
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private object dummyNode = null;
    public string SelectedImagePath { get; set; }

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (string s in Directory.GetLogicalDrives())
        {
            TreeViewItem item = new TreeViewItem();
            item.Header = s;
            item.Tag = s;
            item.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
            item.Items.Add(dummyNode);
            item.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(folder_Expanded);
            folders.Items.Add(item);
        }
    }

    void folder_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        TreeViewItem item = (TreeViewItem)sender;
        if (item.Items.Count == 1 && item.Items[0] == dummyNode)
        {
            item.Items.Clear();
            try
            {
                foreach (string s in Directory.GetDirectories(item.Tag.ToString()))
                {
                    TreeViewItem subitem = new TreeViewItem();
                    subitem.Header = s.Substring(s.LastIndexOf("\\") + 1);
                    subitem.Tag = s;
                    subitem.FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                    subitem.Items.Add(dummyNode);
                    subitem.Expanded += new RoutedEventHandler(folder_Expanded);
                    item.Items.Add(subitem);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception) { }
        }
    }

    private void folders_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<object> e)
    {
        TreeView tree = (TreeView)sender;
        TreeViewItem temp = ((TreeViewItem)tree.SelectedItem);

        if (temp == null)
            return;
        SelectedImagePath = "";
        string temp1 = "";
        string temp2 = "";
        while (true)
        {
            temp1 = temp.Header.ToString();
            if (temp1.Contains(@"\"))
            {
                temp2 = "";
            }
            SelectedImagePath = temp1 + temp2 + SelectedImagePath;
            if (temp.Parent.GetType().Equals(typeof(TreeView)))
            {
                break;
            }
            temp = ((TreeViewItem)temp.Parent);
            temp2 = @"\";
        }


        try
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(SelectedImagePath);
            FileInfo[] content = dir.GetFiles();
            foreach (FileInfo f in content)
            {
                MyFile file = new MyFile();
                file.Name = f.Name;
                file.Extension = f.Extension;
                file.Length = f.Length.ToString();
                ((System.Collections.ArrayList)files.Resources["fileArray"]).Add(file);

            }
        }
        catch (Exception) { }
    }
}
}

<Window x:Class="lab1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:col="clr-namespace:System.Collections;assembly=mscorlib"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:lab1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525" Loaded="Window_Loaded">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TreeView Grid.Column="0" x:Name="folders" SelectedItemChanged="folders_SelectedItemChanged" Width="Auto" Background="#FFFFFFFF" BorderBrush="#FFFFFFFF" Foreground="#FFFFFFFF"/>
        <ListView Grid.Column="1" x:Name="files" ItemsSource="{DynamicResource ResourceKey='fileArray'}">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Name" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=fileName}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Type" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=fileExtension}"></GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Size" Width="70" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=fileLength}"></GridViewColumn>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
            <ListView.Resources>
                <col:ArrayList x:Key="fileArray"></col:ArrayList>
            </ListView.Resources>
        </ListView>
    </Grid>
</Window>

namespace lab1
{
    class MyFile
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Extension { get; set; }
        public string Length { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Таааак...а в чем вопрос? Что не работает? Что получается? Что не получается? :)

Comment: Я нажимаю на каталог, но информация о содержащихся файлах не выводится. Они берутся правильно, но в ListView не передаются никак. В WPF совсем новичок, поэтому не умею координировать работу C# и XAML :'(